# Java malformed url exception for simple url

Tags: java, url, compiler-errors

Frustrating malformed url exception.  As a test, i added the "**URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");**" just to see if a very simple url would throw an error, and it does. I am lost as to what is causing this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Train {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Wikipedesketch1.png"));**
    Integer miles = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the miles"));
    Double gallons = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the gallons"));  
    Double mpg = miles / gallons;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Miles per gallon is " + mpg, "Gass Mileage", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, icon); 
}
```

}

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Unhandled exception type MalformedURLException
    Unhandled exception type MalformedURLException

```
at Train.main(Train.java:13)
```

Comment: The statement doesn't throw an exception. You aren't getting as far as running it, because it's a compile-time error. You need to either catch the potential exception or declare `main()` to throw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have compilation error and none of try/catch for Exception which throws
new ImageIcon()

Try this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Train {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Wikipedesketch1.png"));
        Integer miles = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the miles"));
        Double gallons = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the gallons"));  
        Double mpg = miles / gallons;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Miles per gallon is " + mpg, "Gass Mileage", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, icon);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or OP could declare `main()` to throw an exception.

Comment: Why is there a compilation error with a perfectly normal URL?  that is my sticking point. The new URL object is just for testing and even it is showing the compile error.

Comment: @user1660886 - The compiler error has nothing to do with the URL itself. The URL constructor you are invoking is declared to throw a `MalformedURLException` to cover the possibility that you pass a string that isn't a valid URL. Your code needs to be written to either allow that exception to be thrown within the method (by declaring the `main` method to throw that exception or one of its superclasses, such as `Exception`) or else you need to catch the exception in a `try/catch` statement as Marvin shows in this answer.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it.  It makes sense now.

Comment: No one should ever catch java.lang.Exception.  What if the code has a programming error that generates a NullPointerException?  Also, it is never useful to print a Throwable’s message by itself.  Always call `printStackTrace()` instead, which shows the message with the exception type, and provides information on which line of code generated the exception.

Comment: VGR, the post was not about exceptions, so the solution is generic. Usually applications has logging system to log into file rather than to output in various way, depending you want full information with stack trace or just info.  NullPointerException will be caught also by Exception in above case therefore. But good practice to prevent such exception is by testing variables for null value before working on them.